# Pymongo abandoned "pymongo_kill_cursors_thread" after client exit

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

i have a Python app, which is running jobs in separated threads.
Some workerjobs implement pymongo for a database connection.

```
class Job(Thread):
     ...
     self.client = MongoClient()
```

Every job has a finish method, where

```
self.client.close()
```

is called, when the job is going to terminate. Assumably, this should end all associated threads, but one single thread of every job stays alive:
**pymongo_kill_cursors_thread**

As i am launching multiple jobs, and finishing them, these pymongo_kill_cursors_threads never die and i got them in the hundreds after a short time, here is one example, after a test job finished:

[Result of threading.enumerate()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PUMM.png)

I don't know why the close() method of pymongo doesn't clean up properly, nor if this is a pymongo or mongodb issue.

Trying

```
self.client._kill_cursors_executor._thread.join(1)
```

has no effect, i think its because of the locked state of the thread and the fact, that it is daemon.

Any ideas appreciated. Thank you very much.

*Using "PyMongo", version: "3.5.1" with Python 3.6.1 and MongoDB running in the official docker image*

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it could be a bug, although it requires additional diagnosis. Please open a ticket in the PYTHON project at jira.mongodb.org and provide a complete code example that we can run on our computers that reproduces the error you see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Thanks!